# Click function is failing when page loading take sometime

Tags: karate

I am clicking on Save button but it taking sometime update the changes but click function is failing with reason http call faild after 30002 milliseconds for url http:localhost:63856/session/id/execute/sync

Added readTimeOut and connectionTimeOut as well but not useful

Can someone help me how to resolve this?

It should wait till the successful massage as I have added waitFor

Comment: sorry this sounds like some issue with your webdriver executable or environment. the only way anyone can help is by replicating, so follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue